# LLVM C++ Debugging in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, debugging, llvm, visual-studio-code, debuggervisualizer

I am having a lot of trouble getting the Visual Studio Code debugger to work for my C++ project. I know it isn't a popular IDE for C++ but XCode and Emacs are both equally unsuitable for me. I couldn't even get them to run my code.

I was wondering if anyone could share their .vscode configs that allowed them to use the VCS debugging menu. I would really appreciate it.

P.S. I tried following the tutorial [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md), but largely it has been unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `lldb` as the debugger and programming in **macOS** platform, the answer is quite simple.

`C/C++` extension dose not work well in **macOS**, so I suggest you use [`LLDB Debugger`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vadimcn.vscode-lldb).

If you have installed `python` through **homebrew**, you need do little additional settings following this [issue](https://github.com/vadimcn/vscode-lldb/issues/26) (also there is a PR will fix this but now is waiting to be merged). Maybe you also need run `pip install six` if there is a warning in `lldb` output.

Here is a simple config what i use:

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "lldb",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Debug",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/format",
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Hope I can help you.